# Why does anonymous unique_ptr value get destructed instantly

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How does the object `unique_ptr<A>` behaves if it's passed anonymously (or to no variable at all). How is it possible to know whether the unique_ptr has reference (it's being set into named variable) from within the c'tor.

basically the example shows calling method get() method directly from returned value object.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a):_a(a) {}
    ~A() { std::cout << "d'tor A " << _a << std::endl; }
    int _a;
};


std::unique_ptr<A> f1()
{
    auto p1 = std::make_unique<A>(1);
    return p1;
}

A *f2()
{
    A * x = std::make_unique<A>(2).get(); // d'tor called 2
    std::cout << x->_a << std::endl; // this will print 2 although destructed.
    return x;
}

A *f3()
{
    return std::make_unique<A>(3).get(); // d'tor called 3
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto a=f1();
    auto b=f2();
    auto c=f3();

    return 0;
} // d'tor called 1
```

In the above code, I understand the timing of the `d'tor A 1` call, since when exiting the block where the  unique referrer (denoted by local variable `a`) is destroyed.

But I don't understand the other 2 flows (`d'tor A 2` and `d'tor A 3` that called on the line of the creation - see in example). does it means that reference count in those cases is 0 from the first place, or that it raises to 1 and reduced right after.

P.S

This case intrigued me although it doesn't relate to any real case, but to clarify a concept that I tackled by accident.

It happens because I converted java-script where it's costumed to create a member and use it without intermediate variable (for example `a().b().c()` instead of `_a=a(); _b=_a.b(); _c=_b.c()`) and I accidentally used this notation on my c++ code.

Comment: With e.g. `std::make_unique<A>(2)` you create a *temporary* object. This object will be destructed as soon as the full expression (`std::make_unique<A>(2).get()`) is over.

Comment: `f2` invokes undefined behavior. And both `f2` and `f3` return dangling pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, so you mean that even if it wasn't smart pointer... but just regular call to c'tor of class A, it would still called the d'tor since it's temporary object, right ?

Comment: You would have a similar issue if you have e.g. `A a(2); A* x = &a;` inside the `f2` function.

Comment: It sounds like you are using pointers where values would be preferable. `a().b().c()` can be perfectly reasonable C++

Comment: @caleth, you're right, but In my case I used unique_ptr as temporary variable, and it got destructed instantly as expected, but I thought that It would remain since it wasn't suppose to get dereferenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the lifetime of the `std::unique_ptr` and the object that it manages, with the lifetime of the pointer that you can get using it's `get` method.

A `std::unique_ptr` is the only owner of a dynamically allocated object, when it's destructor is called, it will call a deleter helper function on the pointer it is holding (in case of `std::make_unique`, it will just call `delete` or `delete[]`, whichever is appropriate in this case)

In 1st case, the type of variable `a`, is `std::unique_ptr<A>`, the `std::unique_ptr` lives on the stack, (you didn't have to call `std::move` thanks to copy-elision), and when the `main` function finishes, it's removed from the stack, destructor is called, and the object is deleted, which is the behavior we usually want when using `std::unique_ptr`.

Now, 2nd and 3rd case, are the same, the 2nd case just introduces a temporary variable, but it doesn't change anything.

```cpp
A * x = std::make_unique<A>(2).get();
```

When called like that, you create a temporary `std::unique_ptr<A>`, and on that temporary, you call `get` method, that returns a copy of the pointer that's managed. The issue is that the temporary `std::unique_ptr<A>` is destroyed at the end of the line, and the pointer you have is dangling, it has been already deleted. Dereferencing it and using in anyway is undefined behavior, and anything can happen.

3rd case is the same, temporary `std::unique_ptr`, you're getting it's pointer, but the temporary is removed, so delete is called on the object it was managing, and we have a danging pointer.

Whenever you have a smart pointer, never call `get` on a temporary, 1st store the temporary in a local variable, so it doesn't go out of scope when you're still using the pointer it is managing.